# Run multiple Coldfusion project at the same time

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Right now, I can run one coldfusion at once time. But, I want to run many coldfusion projects at the same time, but I can not do it. Who can share with me. Thank you so much.

When I desploy one project the url :/index.cfm

But now I want to deploy 2 projects : 
url project 1 : /project1/index.cfm 
url project 2 : /project2/index.cfm

Comment: Hi @truongdung0502. You're going to need to improve this question a bit before anyone can answer.  I should flag this but wish to give you benefit of the doubt.  Perhaps explain what issues you're encountering when running multiple projects?

Comment: Maybe you want to run multiple websites on the ColdFusion server, which ist called: multihoming http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=webservmgmt_6.html

Answer (score 2):

This question is very difficult to understand.  However at first glance I think the question is more of an IIS (or whatever web server you are using) question than a coldfusion question.  Simply set up two different websites and point to /project1/index.cfm for one and /project2/index.cfm for the other.